# Convert primitive class to defined class Using OWL Api or Jena api

Tags: class, owl, primitive, protege, defined

I am using OWL API and Jena API.

I need to convert a primitive class to a defined class.

I'm using Protege, I want to do this:

(I'm new in stackoverflow and I can not post pictures, but I put the links.)

I have a class "TestClassInstan" that is a subclass of "TestClass" and has a restriction "hasURL" as shown in Fig [one]:

[one]https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1526873_1383572248568109_2144507550_n.jpg [image: https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1526873_1383572248568109_2144507550_n.jpg]

I want to convert this class and this properties to defined class. And then have this result, a defined class with the propertis equivalent, as shown in Fig [two]:

[two] https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1488649_1383580128567321_1363049007_n.jpg
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you actually want to _convert_ (i.e., remove the prior definition and replace it with a new one) or just _create_ a defined class?

Comment: I want to convert. Could you show me how to do this ?

Comment: For changing one definition to a new one, you'll need to delete the axiom defining the class and add the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pictures in the question are a bit hard to head, so to be clear, in the first, there are two axioms

> *TestClassInstan* **subClassOf** (*hasURL* **value** `"http"`)
>   *TestClassInstan* **subClassOf** *TestClass*

You're looking to remove these two axioms and replace them with a single axiom

> *TestClassInstan* **equivalentClass** (*TestClass* **and** (*hasURL* **value** `"http"`))

[Ignazio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20980710/1281433) has already shown how you can do this using the OWLAPI.  This answer will show how to do it using Jena.  The [OntClass](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html) and [OntModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) interfaces actually provide just about all the methods that you'll need.  The only tricky bit might be constructing the RDFList of classes that make up the intersection, though it's not hard in this example (it's just the list of the original superclasses of *TestClassInstan*).  Here's Java code that accomplishes the conversion.  This also include reconstructing the ontology in code, since you didn't provide actual ontology code.  It's not necessary for the answer, but it might be helpful, and it makes this code stand on its own.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFList;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class ConvertSubclassesToEquivalentIntersection {
    final static String NS = "https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the original model, and show it (just for good measure, so 
        // that we can compare them).
        final OntModel model = createOriginalModel();
        model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );

        // Get the class that we want to convert.
        OntClass testClassInstan = model.createClass( NS+"TestClassInstan" );

        // To create an intersection class, we need an RDFList of the 
        // superclasses, and we can make one of those from the superclass
        // iterator.
        final RDFList superclasses = model.createList( testClassInstan.listSuperClasses( true ));
        testClassInstan.addEquivalentClass( model.createIntersectionClass( null, superclasses ));

        // We still need to remove those superclasses though.
        for ( ExtendedIterator<OntClass> sups = testClassInstan.listSuperClasses( true ); sups.hasNext(); ) {
            testClassInstan.removeSuperClass( sups.next() );
        }

        // Write out the new model.  You can write to a file instead of System.out, 
        // of course, and that's what you'd do to save the model back to a file.
        model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
    }

    /**
     * <p>Recreate the original ontology that had the following axioms (and
     * appropriate class and property declarations):</p>
     * <pre>
     * TestClassInstan subClassOf TestClass
     * TestClassInstan subClassOf (hasURL value "http")
     * </pre>  
     * @return the ontology model
     */
    private static OntModel createOriginalModel() { 
        final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM );

        final OntClass testClass = model.createClass( NS+"TestClass" );
        final OntClass testClassInstan = model.createClass( NS+"TestClassInstan" );
        testClassInstan.addSuperClass( testClass );

        final OntProperty hasURL = model.createDatatypeProperty( NS+"hasURL" );
        final OntClass hasURLValueHttp = model.createHasValueRestriction( null, hasURL, model.createLiteral( "http" ));
        testClassInstan.addSuperClass( hasURLValueHttp );

        return model;
    }
}
```

The original ontology is:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/TestClass"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/TestClassInstan">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:hasValue>http</owl:hasValue>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/hasURL"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/TestClass"/>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

[image: original ontology]

And the converted ontology is:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/TestClass"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/TestClassInstan">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:hasValue>http</owl:hasValue>
            <owl:onProperty>
              <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/hasURL"/>
            </owl:onProperty>
          </owl:Restriction>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433/TestClass"/>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

[image: after conversion]

Comment: Thank you for your help.

This works correctly if the ontology is created with the method "createOriginalModel". But otherwise if the classes and the axioms already exist in the ontology, and the code of the method "createOriginalModel" is not called, this code doesn't work. 

I do not understand why.

And since I'm working with classes and axioms that exist in the ontology, I need to clarify this.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? You'll need to save the ontology to file again, of course. Are you doing that?

Comment: This is the initial ontology. This Ontology have the two axioms of which we have discussed: [OntInic] https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/36598_1385929438332390_183163843_n.jpg

I compiled the following code to modify the initial ontology, to remove these two axioms and replace them with a single axiom.
`TestClassInstan equivalentClass (TestClass and (hasURL value "http"))`

The code:

Comment: `final OntModel modeler = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM );
PrintStream p= new PrintStream(inputFileName);  
OntClass testClassInstan = modeler.createClass( NS+"TestClassInstan" );
final RDFList superclasses = modeler.createList( testClassInstan.listSuperClasses( true ));
testClassInstan.addEquivalentClass( modeler.createIntersectionClass( null, superclasses ));
for ( ExtendedIterator<OntClass> sups = testClassInstan.listSuperClasses( true ); sups.hasNext(); ) {
 testClassInstan.removeSuperClass( sups.next() );
}
modeler.write(p, "RDF/XML-ABBREV", null);
p.close();`

Comment: And as a result of this, I have this ontology: [resultOnt] https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/p206x206/1555576_1385924581666209_51569379_n.jpg


The code removes two previous axioms,  but it creates a empty equivalent axiom, as shown in Figure [resultOnt].

Could you show me what is wrong with the code ?I would appreciate your help.

Pda: This figure shows the code in a better way [code]https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/182985_1385924558332878_207943369_n.jpg

Comment: @FabianG in that code, you're starting with an empty model, so testclassinstan doesn't have any duperclasses to begin with, so the list is empty, and you create an intersection of 0 classes. You still need to load the original ontology from file.

Comment: @FabianG To load the file after you've created an empty model, you'd just do `model.read("/path/to/file.owl");`.  You could also use an input stream, etc.  This is all laid out fairly plainly in the [Javadoc for Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html).

Answer (score 2):

In the OWL API, there is no need for any special conversion to turn a primitive concept in a defined one. Simply add the axioms that define your class. For example, if `A` is your class, and you want to define it as equivalent to an existential restriction like `some r C`, you just create an axiom:

```
Set<OWLClassExpression> arguments=new HashSet<OWLClassExpression>();
arguments.add(A);
arguments.add(dataFactory.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(r, C);
OWLAxiom axiom = dataFactory.getOWLEquivalentClassesAxiom(arguments);
```

and add this axiom to the ontology. `A` will now be a defined concept.

Note: the code above will not modify the ontology file. To save the ontology, use

```
ontologyManager.saveOntology(ontology)
```

Comment: I try this, with this code:

[code]https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1507558_1384475221811145_1739071279_n.jpg

The class classAlpha is this:
[class] https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1497612_1384473251811342_1401738201_n.jpg

but it doesn't work, No changes were made ​​in the class or in the ontology.

Could you show me what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: In the Protégé example, it looks like the original subclass axioms were removed, and I've included removing them in [my Jena-based answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21001185/1281433).  Adding the new equivalent classes axiom won't remove the earlier subclass axioms, will it?

Comment: Correct, to change an existing definition it is first necessary to remove the corresponding axiom. I didn't add that to my example because the question said "primitive class", so it should not already have a definition :-)